# How can I improve this trial division procedure?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

My background is procedural programming, so I find this construction quite natural.  Is there a way to get rid of the `While`?

```
gd[n_, k_] := Block[{d = k + 1}, While[0 != Mod[n, --d]]; d]
gd[n_, d_List] := 
      Block[{j = Length[d] + 1}, While[0 != Mod[n, d[[--j]]]]; d[[j]]]  

k = 4; n = 25;
gd[n, k]
gd[n, Range[1, k]]
d = Join[{1}, Table[Prime[j], {j, 1, PrimePi[k]}]];
gd[n, d]
```

My trial division requires the greatest divisor $\leq$ the square root. The $n$ mod $1$ is the terminating step. Whatever the final format, I will need to describe it for a math paper.

**Edit**  The revised functions as recursions:

```
gd[n_, k_] := If[Mod[n, k] == 0, k, gd[n, k - 1]]
fd[n_, d_List] := If[Mod[n, d[[1]]] == 0, d[[1]], fd[n, Delete[d, 1]]]
```

**Edit** The second function as it will be described in my paper:

$$f(n,D)\text{:=}
\begin{array}{ll}
 \lbrace & 
\begin{array}{ll}
 n \bmod d_{1}=0 & d_{1} \\
 n \bmod d_{1}\neq 0 & f(n,\text{Delete}(D,1)) \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Do you want the greatest proper divisor or the greatest prime divisor? If the former, check for primes beginning at 2 and take the cofactor of the first one that divides your number. If the latter, start at sqrt(n) and work downward, again checking only primes. Either way, precompute your primes and store their differences; that gives you the increment/decrement to use as you go up/down the list.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I put the new functions in the OP. The second one allows me to use a list of divisors, which can be primes or all numbers below the square root.

Comment: A bit long for a comment, but...your fd[] will require both deep recursion/iteration and also has quadratic complexity. Much more efficient to use Map or Scan. I show by way of example. In[658]:= $IterationLimit = Infinity; 
fd[n_, d_List] := If[Mod[n, d[[1]]] == 0, d[[1]], fd[n, Delete[d, 1]]]

In[659]:= e1 = Prime[8000]*Prime[9000]^2;
rng = Prime[Range[20000, 1, -1]];

In[661]:= Timing[fd[e1, rng]]

Out[661]= {4.630000, 93179}

In[662]:= fd2[n_, d_List] := Scan[(If[Mod[n, #] == 0, Return[#]]) &, d]

In[663]:= Timing[fd2[e1, rng]]

Out[663]= {0.010000, 93179}

Comment: @Daniel I often see unformatted code in your comments.  Are you aware that you can wrap the code in backticks to get `code`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
     gd[n_, k_] := If[Mod[n, k] == 0, k, gd[n, k - 1]]
```

Comment: Very nice! Should be easy to explain in the paper.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a functional way to do the first definition for `gd`:

```
f[n_, k_] := NestWhile[# - 1 &, k, Mod[n, #] != 0 &]
```

I'll leave the second one to you. In general, whenever you encounter repeated application of a particular function, think of `Nest` (use `Fold`, for more general cases). Combined with a `While` loop, you need `NestWhile`, which is what I used above.

Test this with your function for a bunch of test cases:

```
With[{list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {100, 2}]}, gd @@@ list == f @@@ list]
(* True *)
```